# Player running over boxCollider 2D unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, c3.js, collider

So I made a project with a player and tilemap dungeon, I worked on getting a collider working for the tilemap but turns out the collider doesnt even work for any other objects. The player just runs over it without any reaction. I have included the neccessary components like a box collider and rigidbody etc. but it still wont work.[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6WqH.png)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Kgbd.png)

I even made another "test" project and it was the same result there. Asked a few people i know and they told me they have no clue, as it should not be a problem.

Comment: post player controller code

Comment: We need more infothan these 2 images

Comment: If there's anything else that might help us, please add it to the question